# count the size of table and set to cucumber capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

Hi I am very new to cucumber. I try to click multiple button in same time.

[image]

Its my stucture. Here I need to click on every delete button. so what i was trying is

```
When /^remove contact manitary field$/ do
s = page.all('#contact-mapping-table tbody tr').size
s.to_i.times do
  within all("#contact-mapping-table tbody tr td.delete")[0] do
   click_on("Delete")
  end 
 end
 click_on("Save")
end
```

But its not working. I don't know what wrong in this. How may I click every delete button one by one or any have.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
rows = page.all('#contact-mapping-table tbody tr')
rows.each do |raw|
  within raw do
    # Can't use word "Delete" here since no word in link
    find('.delete-button-class').click 
    # better to wait for a while depending on real situation. Not verified.
    sleep 1 
  end
end
click "Save"
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. I tried you code. But its not working. Here `rows` output value is zero. But I have 5 rows. I just follow you exact code.

Comment: @Selva, if the size is zero, it's the CSS selector has problem. You need to verify that in your browser and update it accordingly. I know nothing about your selectors, just copied it, it should work if selector is right.

Comment: Also you need to change the button's class according to yours, instead of use it exactly.

Comment: I tryed this code. Its output is **Zero** `rows = page.all('div#account-overview table.table tbody tr')
  puts rows` Is there any mistake here?

Comment: @Selva, sorry, I just copied your code which is incorrect. I double checked it. The code should be `rows = all(....` instead of `rows = page.all(...`. There should be no `page`.

Comment: Hi its my full code `When /^remove contact manitary field$/ do
  rows = all('#contact-mapping-table tbody tr')
  rows.each do |raw|
    within raw
      # Can't use word "Delete" here since no word in link
      find('.remove_nested_fields').click 
      # better to wait for a while depending on real situation. Not verified.
      sleep 1 
    end
end`  But Its not work  :(

Comment: I don't have your full code and don't understand what "not work" means if you don't tell the error part explicitly. My answer is supposed to provide an approach or an idea you can work on, it by no means could be working code.

Comment: Ho sorry, The error message is `no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)`

Comment: thanks its work fine after added `do` in 3rd line of your code.

Comment: @Selva, sorry, basic mistake by me :)